# Dynamic variables based on input

Tags: github-actions

I want a `workflow_dispatch` workflow with an input for environment but then throughout the workflows there are a bunch of values that change based on environment.

Is there a way I can select a set of variables based the selected environment?

For example, I need an AWS IAM Role ARN for the workflow to use, there's a different role for each environment.

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        description: The environment to deploy to
        required: true
        type: choice
        options:
          - "test"
          - "cert"
          - "prod"

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
        with:
          aws-region: eu-west-1
          role-session-name: Build
          role-to-assume: # What to use here?
```

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#environment-variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd personally use variables stored at the GitHub environment level. Then reference the environment in the job:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        description: The environment to deploy to
        required: true
        type: choice
        options:
          - "test"
          - "cert"
          - "prod"

jobs:
  build:
    environment: ${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
        with:
          aws-region: eu-west-1
          role-session-name: Build
          role-to-assume: ${{ vars.role }}
```

[image]

In each environment, create variables (and secrets) with the exact same name for the values that need to be unique at the environment level. Variables created at the repo level will be used as default values

[image]

You can even go as far as to define the type in the dropdown as `environment` and it will automatically populate the list:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        description: 'The environment to deploy to'
        type: environment
        required: true
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't want to use the environments for this job because we have deployment approvals required and I wanted the artifacts to build before that. I was hoping for another option but it looks like this is the way to do it so will have to rethink the workflow I guess.

Comment: There's some trickery you can do by setting the variables from a script.